# Where should I put the .pdbrc file on windows so that it is globally visible?

Tags: python

I am using .pdbrc to store my debugging alias. And I want it to be available globally. Where should this file be on windows?

Answer (score 1):

After several tries, I found it.
You can put it in **C:\users\your_win_user\.pdbrc**

Answer (score 1):

If putting the file in `C:\Users\<your_user>` doesn't work, additionaly try setting your `HOME` environment variable to `C:\Users\<your_user>`. Worked for me.

Thanks to @WayneWerner for the solution.