# How can I define .pdbrc on a Windows machine?

Tags: python, windows, pdb

How can I define `.pdbrc` on my Windows machine?

My `.pdbrc` file:

```
alias sl s;;l
alias nl n;;l
alias cl c;;l
```

After reading the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438478/where-should-i-put-the-pdbrc-file-on-windows-so-that-it-is-globally-visible), I tried putting it in `C:\Users\<my_user>`. Starting `pdb` (using `pdb.set_trace()`), I tried the aliases. They weren't recognized.

I'd like to know how to set a `.pdbrc` both globally, and for a virtual environment.

Comment: what does `import os; print(os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser('~')))` give you? Also, how about your `HOME` env var? Presumably they're the same...

Comment: @WayneWerner I don't have a `HOME` environment variable. Is it present on Windows machines by default?

Comment: @WayneWerner Anyway, I just created it and set it to `C:\Users\<my_user>`. The Python expression you gave prints out the same result. Still, `.pdbrc` doesn't work.

Comment: @WayneWerner My bad, after restarting `cmd.exe` the aliases now work! Guess I needed to set the `HOME` environment variable. Want to post this as an answer? Thanks

Comment: This should be fixed in pdb. It's [checking `HOME`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Lib/pdb.py#l76) instead of using the cross-platform alternative, `os.path.expanduser('~')`.

Comment: As a followup note -- some users appear to have `HOME` set as a system-level environment variable equal to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`. On Windows 10, this expands as desired for the current user, but on Win 7 (at least with default configuration, it does not, presumably because system env vars must all be defined before user ones, so this can't be expanded. Obviously if it doesn't expand then the user's .pdbrc won't be found.

Answer (score 1):

`pdb` [looks for the `HOME` system variable](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/33fd60d4c3fd95ef1c8edf83bd4a3c203edc1cad/Lib/pdb.py#L162) which is not defined by default in Windows.  You have to define it yourself.

This issue arises because every user in a *nix operating system (Linux, Unix, Darwin, etc.) has a `/home` directory where they can put run codes like `.pdbrc`.  The path to this directory lives in a system variable (`HOME`) that applications use to point to a user's personal files.  [Windows doesn't really have anything like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228950/what-is-the-alternative-for-users-home-directory-on-windows-command-prompt).  The closest analogy to `/home` on Windows is probably `C:\Users\<username>`.

Here is how to define a `HOME` system variable that contains the path `C:\Users\<username>`.  Left click on the startup button and then right click on "Computer" and select "Properties".

[image: Click the startup menu > right click "Computer" > select "Properties"]

On the top left, click the "Advanced system settings" link.

[image: Click advanced system settings]

This brings up the "System Properties" dialog.  On the "Advanced" tab, press the "Environment variables..." button.

[image: Click the "Environment Variables..." button]

This brings up the "Environment Variables..." dialog.  In the top section for "User variables for `<username>`", press the "New..." button.

[image: Press "New..." in the User Variables section]

For "Variable name:" put "HOME" and for "Variable value:" put `C:\Users\<username>`.

[image: Enter "HOME" and path to what you want HOME to be]

If a `HOME` variable already exists, just put a semi-colon between whatever is the current value and the new path.  When an application uses the `HOME` variable, it will likely search the contents sequentially.  If you want your new path to be found first, put it first in the list.

Hit "Okay" a bunch and then restart whatever application (`cmd.exe` or otherwise) is running `pdb`.  Make sure that your `.pdbrc` file is in `C:\Users\<username>`.  When you run `pdb` again, it should now read your `.pdbrc` file on startup.